# Bluetooth save chat history in android

Tags: android

is there any way to store bluetooth chat history device wise.if yes then please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy on not depending on the communication technology you're using. Just write all the incoming messages into a file/data structure/however you want to store them.